# Debugging React components in spfx client side webparts

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, debugging, react

How can I step through my .tsx code file line by line? Either using Google Chromes developer tools or Visual studio code the debugger steps into internal Typescript/JavaScript libraries?

It becomes very time consuming debugging the pnp js API calls this way.

How do I only step through my own Typescript code files and not have to step through the millions of lines in the internal libraries?

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you debugging on workbench page ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I am debugging on workbench.aspx page

Comment: In your developer tools, find the webpack folder and then attach to debugger, check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGyUm.png)

Comment: Thanks for your help Gautam. Though this is something I am already doing.